# Blender keeps adding "limit location" bone constraint to an entire armature?

Tags: armature, bones, constraints

Just move to 2.8.

I am unable to add bone constraint: limit location to a bone in an armature.  Everytime I try, the constraint is applied to the entire armature.

What gives?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're confusing bone constraints with object constraints? To give a bone a constraint, you need to switch your armature to *Pose* mode, then you'll have access to the *Bone Constraints* tab, which is not the same as the *Object Constraints* tab.

Shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I guess that is what happened.  What is the hotkey for adding bone constraints?

Comment: Shortcut ctrl shift C